# Reading and Writing EXIF data - Ionic/Cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, jpeg, exif

I'm working on an Ionic project that takes a picture of a soil sample and determines the dominant color in the soil sample.  Once that RGB value is determined I would like to be able to store it into the EXIF data so that it can be retrieved in a "Previous Results" tab.  I was wondering if anyone has any idea on how this can be done.

Comment: Is there an Exif "Previous Results" tag or our you making this up? I am not aware of one.

Comment: No, what I'm thinking is the pictures would be stored in the apps local storage and if the user clicked on the previous results tab all of the pictures they took would be listed and they could click on it and there would be a javascript script that could read the EXIF data out of the image and display it to the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store your own data, the JPEG way to do it is using an APPn marker. If you need to store a lot of data, you might have to change markers. You need to look in the JPEG standard for what you want. The APPn markers have a length field so you can put anything you want in them.

You should probably:
1. Select an APPn marker not used by the major file formats; and
2. Include an Aapplication identifier at the start of the marker.